# Changing in runtime the number of the component of the PickerView with NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipickerview, nsuserdefaults

Hello everybody Im a newbie about iPhone programming
 I created an application with a tab bar.In one view there's a picker view in other view I put a slider where I want change the number of the components of  the picker. Even if I use nsuserdefaults and then reloadAllcomponents the number of picker component doesn't change.
Can someone help to resolve this issue? How can this two communicate without use setting bundle but only nsuserdefaults?
Thanks

Comment: make sure your count is count is coming from  UserDefault every time and it is reflecting changes you did.

Answer (score 1):

You need to `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];` after writing to them in one class and before reading in other class?

Comment: This is the code associate with slide value changing:   
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setInteger:mySlider.value forKey:@"value"]; 
    
    myLabel.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%i",[defaults integerForKey:@"value"]];
   
    [defaults synchronize];
   
    myClass.components=[defaults integerForKey:@"value"];// this is a variable contains the number of component in the other view
    [myClass.picker numberOfComponents];
    NSLog(@"@%i",myClass.components);
    [myClass.picker reloadAllComponents];

Comment: Could you update your question to include code of both view controllers?